# 2SLS in Stata with interaction term

Tags: stata, interaction

I am running a two-stage least squares (2SLS) regression in Stata (panel data). I have one exogenous variable (`x1`), one endogenous variable (`x2`), and one instrument for `x2` (`z`).
I interested in the effect of `x2` on `y`, and in particular in the effect of the interaction `x1*x2` on `y`.

What I wrote is:

```
xtivreg2 2sls y x1 (x2 c.x2#i.x1 = z i.z#i.x1), fe
```

I always get error message "operator invalid" for `c.x2#i.x1`.

Could anyone help here?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use factor variable notation and define them by hand:

```
use http://fmwww.bc.edu/ec-p/data/macro/abdata.dta, clear
tsset id year
gen nk = n*k
gen l2nk = l2.n*k
xtivreg2 ys k (n nk = l2.n l2nk), fe
```

However, this may be a bad idea for forbidden regression reasons. Take a look at [this Statalist thread](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2003-11/index.html#00795), especially Mark's response.

Comment: As a follow-up question: how can you interact with the effect of x2 when it can be instrumented by z1 and z2?